# How to correctly indent when beginning a new line below the cursor ('o')?

Tags: indentation, filetype

## Screenshots

[image: vim screenshot]
[image]

## My problem

I am working on a `js` file, using `eslint` as my linter with the [ale plugin](https://github.com/w0rp/ale), configured using the `airbnb` standard which mandates 2 space indentation.

When I open a new line by hitting `o`, the new line is indented with 4 spaces, regardless of the filetype. I have set `tabstop=4`, but I want this to change for `js` files according the the rules of my linter.

## My `.vimrc`

```
" General settings
syntax on
set rulerformat=%l,%c%V%=%P
set ruler
set relativenumber      " Current line number is absolute, others relative. Makes j-k jumps easier
set number              " Show line numbers
set tabstop=4           " Show tabs as 4 spaces
set shiftwidth=4        " Indent with 4 spaces when > is pressed
set expandtab           " Indent with 4 spaces when > is pressed
set cursorline          " Highlight current line
filetype on             " :help filetype - Auto-detect the current file type, by name and content
filetype plugin on      " :help filetype - Enable loading the plugin files for specific file types

" Appearance
colorscheme tayra


" Plugin installation using Plug
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'w0rp/ale'
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
Plug 'mhinz/vim-sayonara'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
call plug#end()

" Plugin options
let g:ale_linters = {'javascript': ['eslint']}
let g:ale_javascript_eslint_executable='/usr/local/bin/eslint'
```

## What have I tried

Searching the net, and adding `filetype on` and `filetype plugin on` to my `.vimrc` file.

## My question

How can I set the indentation to automatically suit the current file type?

Comment: is your vim always doing 4 spaces for a tab, or is the problem just the new line ?

Answer (score 1):

Vim help says:

> You can enable loading the plugin files for specific file types with:
>
> `:filetype plugin on`
>
> If filetype detection was not switched on yet, it will be as well. *The result is that when a file is edited its plugin file is loaded (if there is one for the detected filetype)*.

Plugin file is just a regular Vim script. To make indentation 2 spaces long for `js` files you need to create a file `.vim/ftplugin/javascript.vim`:

```
setlocal tabstop=2
setlocal shiftwidth=2
```

You want to use `setlocal` instead of `set` because `set` changes both local and global values (thus changing the value for all open buffers).